# Spark cache disk VS cache memory

Tags: caching, apache-spark, cluster-computing

[image]
 I have a question about the follow picture.I use *data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)*
to cache our original data,but what is so surprised is that the speed we cached in memory is the same as the speed we cached in disk?why?I feel the speed we cached in memory should be faster than the speed we cached in disk,who can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong, this is because Spark is not writing directly to disk.

For `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` persistence level, the RDD that could fit into memory would be left there (same as MEMORY_ONLY), and only if it was too big for memory would it spill to disk.

So I presume you do not have problem there, it is normal that you will see these times, until your memory is full then you will start to see longer time to write the data to disk.

Comment: Thank you.And my dataset is 50g,and --executor-memory is default 1g,I use --executor-num 4 ,how can RDD fit dataset into memory?

Comment: It depends how big is your RDD at the moment you are trying to cache it.
I understand your dataset size is a size of file(s), not of objects in memory? 
You would need at least as much memory as big is your RDD, that's the first thing. Also, you can see what percent of RDD is cached in memory on some tab, I do not remember which one, just click around a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the StorageLevel `DISK_ONLY` VS `MEMORY_ONLY`and increase your input data size.